# VBA Create Multi Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba

Code was running with no error pop-out, but no pivot table is showing in tab Apple# and Banana#.There must be something wrong.
Hope someone could check my code.. or teach me a better way to do this.

```
Sub TableTesting()

Dim PAppleSheet, PBananaSheet As Worksheet
Dim DAppleSheet, DBananaSheet As Worksheet
Dim AppleCache1, AppleCache2, BananaCache1, BananaCache2 As PivotCache
Dim AppleTable1, AppleTable2, BananaTable1, BananaTable2 As PivotTable
Dim PAppleRange, PBananaRange As Range
Dim LastRowApple, LastRowBanana As Long
Dim LastColApple, LastColBanana As Long

'Apple

On Error Resume Next

Set PAppleSheet = Worksheets("Apple#")
Set DAppleSheet = Worksheets("Apple")

LastRowApple = DAppleSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastColApple = DAppleSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PAppleRange = DAppleSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)


Set AppleCache1 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PAppleRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PAppleSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
TableName:="AppleSTRTable1")

Set AppleTable1 = AppleCache1.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PAppleSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="AppleSTRTable1")


With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AppleSTRTable1").PivotFields("Sender")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With


With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AppleSTRTable1").PivotFields("Amount")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Function = xlSum
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
.Name = "Amount "


End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AppleSTRTable1").PivotFields("Amount")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Function = xlCount
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
.Name = "Item "

End With


Set AppleCache2 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PAppleRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PAppleSheet.Cells(1, 6), _
TableName:="AppleSTRTable2")

Set AppleTable2 = AppleCache2.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PAppleSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="AppleSTRTable2")


With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AppleSTRTable2").PivotFields("Sender")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AppleSTRTable2").PivotFields("Color")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 2
End With


With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AppleSTRTable2").PivotFields("Amount")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Function = xlSum
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
.Name = "Amount "


End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AppleSTRTable2").PivotFields("Amount")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Function = xlCount
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
.Name = "Item "

End With

'Banana

On Error Resume Next

Set PBananaSheet = Worksheets("Banana#")
Set DBananaSheet = Worksheets("Banana")

LastRowBanana = DBananaSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastColBanana = DBananaSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PBananaRange = DBananaSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)


Set BananaCache1 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PBananaRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PBananaSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
TableName:="BananaSTRTable1")

Set BananaTable1 = BananaCache1.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PBananaSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="BananaSTRTable1")


With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("BananaSTRTable1").PivotFields("Sender")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With


With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("BananaSTRTable1").PivotFields("Amount")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Function = xlSum
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
.Name = "Amount "


End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("BananaSTRTable1").PivotFields("Amount")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Function = xlCount
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
.Name = "Item "

End With


Set BananaCache2 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PBananaRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PBananaSheet.Cells(1, 6), _
TableName:="BananaSTRTable2")

Set BananaTable2 = BananaCache2.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PBananaSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="BananaSTRTable2")


With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("BananaSTRTable2").PivotFields("Sender")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("BananaSTRTable2").PivotFields("Color")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 2
End With


With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("BananaSTRTable2").PivotFields("Amount")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Function = xlSum
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
.Name = "Amount "


End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("BananaSTRTable2").PivotFields("Amount")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Function = xlCount
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
.Name = "Item "

End With
```

End Sub

Comment: You have `On Error Resume Next`. Try commenting this out and you should then see if there are any errors. As it stands, even if there is an error, you are telling the compiler to just move to the next line of code

Comment: As @Zac says, it would be helpful to know exactly where the error occurs.

Comment: @Zac I removed 'On Error Resume Next'.. pop up application defined error. do you know which one has error on? If I run only single table.. it works fine..

Comment: It would be very difficult for me to run your code without the data. Can you provide some more details like: which line does the error occur? what is the error?